# Как это работает? Pandas, groupby, get_group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Пусть есть таблица df , в ней есть колонки с названием
"имя", "класс".
Пусть есть строчки с именем "x".
Если:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("имя")
df_one_group = df_grouped.get_group("x")
df_one_group = df_one_group[["имя", "класс"]]
```

Соответственно вылезает ошибка тк колонки "имя" нету,
но если завернуть цикл то все работает как надо:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("имя")
for i in df["имя"].unique():  
    df_one_group = df_grouped.get_group(i)
    df_one_group = df_one_group[["имя", "класс"]]
```

Почему в цикле все хорошо, а без него вылезает ошибка?

Comment: Так у вас все-таки "имя" или "Имя"?

Comment: там  одинаково должно быть, спасибо

Comment: У меня работают оба варианта. Ошибка в первом варианте (без цикла) может быть только тогда, когда у вас отсутствует в столбце "имя" значение "х".

Comment: Но если вывести df_one_group (df_one_group = df_grouped.get_group("x")) , то выведутся все столбцы исключая , тот по которому бралась группировка . Разве нет ?

Comment: Мне что-то вообще не понятно, что вы хотели сказать в последнем комменте. либо у вас с типом скобок путаница, либо еще что. Пожалуйста, исправьте свой вопрос так. чтобы было понятно, чего вы хотите добиться, приведите исходный датафрейм и пример желаемого результата.

Comment: нет.если вы явно на зададите столбцы, которые хотите вывести.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я сейчас попробовал и нашел свою проблему. Если я делаю df_one_group.first() перед get_group, то потом он не выводит столбец «имя»

Comment: Я там опять ошибся df_grouped.first()

Comment: Вы можете внести исправления в свой вопрос.

Comment: Ну там вопрос тогда про first получается. Тут я хотяб знаю, что искать , так что покопаюсь в документации.спасибо